# how to execute custom executable in android

Tags: android

We have an custom executable (created custom executable by compiling source on Ubuntu) and that we are copying to `/data/data/app-package/bin` and then we are trying to execute it using processbuidler but it does nothing. We are passing command like `/system/bin/sh path-to-executable option` or have tried `path-to-executable options` but no luck.

After some googling we found that data folder might not have access to execute anything so then how to execute custom executable in android.

Comment: If it is compiled for the correct architecture and linked against the android libraries and has the execute bit set, it should be able to work.  Try giving the full pathname of the program.  You don't need to invoke a shell, unless you are using some shell capability.